# Getting ipad device information using safari web browser

Tags: objective-c, ipad, safari, mobile-safari

We have an web application which users access from the iPad safari web browser.We want certain kind of analytic about the users.
I want to know what information can i get through the safari browser about the user`s iPad.Can i access
1) iOS version installed.
3) Safari web browser version.
2) UDID of device.

Comment: How is Objective-C involved in this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze the [User Agent ID](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html#apple), and it will tell you which iOS version is used and the version number of MobileSafari, but AFAIK there is no way to query the UDID (luckily, I might add, since that'll be an even nastier privacy issue than cookies already are).