# Get unique token for device in HTML/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on web application where application will be opened in browsers on tablets . Application will be run on multiple tablets at a time. I want to know if there is any way by which I can uniquely identify the tablet on which application is running , basically something like device token?

Comment: generate a random number on the first visit, save that to localStorage, send with requests.

Comment: If your plan is get stats, then you can use google analytics, it will give you complete details of the devices your application is running on.

Comment: Do you have a user login?

Comment: Same questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764115/can-i-retrieve-an-ipad-unique-device-identifier-that-through-safari-with-a-js-we and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089361/getting-ipad-device-information-using-safari-web-browser

Comment: you can use font/canvas fingerprinting if you need to detect machines even after cookies/localStorage is cleared...

Comment: @jfriend00 yes I do have user login

Comment: So, why don't you use the login cookie to uniquely identify each tablet then?

Comment: I am looking for something that can persists even after logout.I dont want be dependent on user login , but want to have something that can uniquely identify the device

Answer (score 0):

Well ... This can be done but you risk duplicates in the long run to be honest. Here is how you can **try** to keep it as random as possible ->

This encodes a random set of digits, the userAgent and the Date in base64, but you should honestly be using something more reliable server side.

```
var id = btoa( Math.random() + navigator.userAgent + Date() );
```

Example Below ::

```js
function id() {
  document.getElementById('code').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',( btoa( Math.random() + navigator.userAgent + Date() ) ) + '<br>' );
}
document.getElementById('click').addEventListener('click',id,false);
```

```html
<input id='click' type='button' value='click'><br>
<div id='code'></div>
```

Comment: do you know what the odds of a duplicate are with that code?

Comment: A benchmark should be done, but the odds would be pretty low

Comment: my point is don't talk down your solution: you have MUCH better odds of being both struck by lighting and winning the lotto on your birthday than you do of seeing a dupe...